# mongoose where query with date range

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am new with mongoose and I am trying to create a where query in a requests table that has a start date of vacation and end date of vacation. I am trying to check if the user is trying to insert a new vacation where the date entered is within a range that already exists in the table

Example:

> **New Request:** employee_id: 1, start_date: 27-12-2020, end_date: 01-01-2021

> **record in DB:** employee_id:1, start_date: 25-12-2020 , end_date: 30-12-2020

Can't insert new request since user already requested a vacation within that range before.since he can not have 2 vacations requested at the same time.

**Request Schema:**

```
const requests_Schema = mongoose.Schema({

employee_id : {
    required: true,
    type: String
},
start_date: {
    type:Date,
    required: true
},
end_date: {
    type:Date,
    required: true
}

});
```

******Creating a new request:******

```
let newRequest = new requests_Model({
            employee_id: req.body.employee_id,
            request_type: "Compensation Leave",
            start_date: req.body.start_date,
            end_date: req.body.end_date
        })
```

**Query:**

```
  requests_Schema.pre('save',()=>{
            let emp_id = this.employee_id
            let start_date = this.start_date
            let end_date - this.end_date
            requests_Model.find({employee_id:emp_id}) 
                //WHERE new vacation date range doesn't conflict with any old vacation range
                //If it does I shouldn't insert that request, user not allowed to

            }
```

Kindly help me execute such a query because I'm finding it hard to.